# GCP Adwords Permissions for IAM Member

Tags: gcp, google-iam

I have a requirement to use cross-project access to a Google Ads (Adwords) service. That is, ProjectA has a VM in it, which has a Service Account. This has cross-project access to ProjectB, which has an IAM member in it allowing the Service Account 'editor' access, which (hopefully) provides access to Adwords (the 'editor' role is the basic, general one).

I'm aware that my Service Account -> IAM Member linkage allows more access in ProjectB than it should. I'm looking to limit that down by any means that are possible. However, I can't find any built-in roles that look suitable, and I can't make my own custom role because I can't find any underlying permissions for Adwords. I also wondered if there was maybe a way to limit to just the specific API, but again, can't find anything about that anywhere either.

What options do I have? How can I limit an IAM Member to (only) access Adwords?

Answer (score 0):

Oh gees... Having given the developer the usual lecture about using Service Accounts rather than API keys, it turns out Google Ads **cannot** use a Service Account. The SDK for Google Ads can **only** use a "[Developer Token](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/get-started/dev-token)" - of which there can only ever be one, it never rotates or expires (so about the worst sort of authentication there is).

Google Ads has its [own SDK](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-ruby), separate from the regular [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk?hl=en). The Google Ads one can't use a Service Account, and the Cloud SDK can't use Google Ads.